# I'm trying to decipher my logcat info for an app that hangs up, and I need some pointers

Tags: android

Here is some background on what I have going on. I am learning as I go, so I might have some difficuities with terminology. I have a main activity that needs to connect to a bluetooth module. The main activity creates an object called mChatService from another java file called BluetoothChatService.java.

```
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;
```

So, in the main activity I have a function that is called connectDevice(). According to my logcat this function is entered into as expected. But when it reaches as certian line of code it hangs up. The line of code is this,  mChatService.connect(device,secure); Now by checking the logcat errors this is what I find:

```
1639 BluetoothService.cpp stopDiscoveryNative:D-bus error instopDiscovery:
org.bluez.Error.Failed(invalid discovery session)
```

Also another window pops up next to my java files, that reads:

```
ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActitvityThread$ActivityClientRecord, List) line: 2655
```

So, my question is, Is this enough info to suggest a possible explanation of the problem that is occuring? If not, what would be my next step in gathering info that might be useful for debugging?

Comment: I'm already getting voted down....Really, I've asked a very specific question, Is this enough info to suggest a possible explanation? A yes or no would have been sufficeint....

Comment: Is this a forum for EXPERTS only? It seems I just get voted down alot with out any explanations......

Comment: Have a balance upvote. Also please copy the whole error log from the LogCat output alongside with the relevant lines of code.

Comment: Hey, thinksteep, did you edit my code to look like that? If you did thanks! I appreciate it! Maybe thats one of the reasons help has been fleeting... I will work on my formatting.

Comment: Have another vote. There are some strange folk on here...

Comment: I have been trying to copy the Logcat, but I have not found a way. The thing just keeps scrolling up, and I can't get it to stop. Is there a way to stop it. I've also tried to click copy and paste to no avail.